# get mail from fail2ban only if aspecific ip(range) is blocked

Tags: fail2ban

is it possible to get only mails from fail2ban if a specific IP(range) is blocked?

I got it configured that I got mails if an IP blocked, which works fine

Comment: I guess this requires a special mail action which filters itself